# Database design for posts that's not been moderated

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

So, there are posts that's been moderated which means that it's visible to all users and the posts that hasn't which means that it's only visible to the moderators.

So, which one has better performance?
1. Having two tables which is 'posts' and 'unmoderated_posts'; then, after the moderator accepts the post, the row from unmoderatedd_posts will be move to 'posts'
2. Having just one table which is 'posts' with column _isVisible, if the value is 1, it means that all users can see it, but if it's 0, only moderator can see it

Comment: Perhaps read up about partitioning - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: @EdHeal what's this got to do with partitioning?

Comment: Partition the table into moderated posts and unmoderated posts to get better performance

Comment: Re: partitioning: changing `_isVisible` is effectively a `DELETE` from one partition and an `INSERT` into the other.  Essentially the same cost as the "two table" approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second options seems better as you have just one concept: 'posts'. If they are moderated or not is just a property inside that single concept.

Also, having two different tables will add extra complexity to your code which, probably, will affect your general performance.